# BEHAT - Not able to execute the test in browsers

Tags: selenium, automation, behat

I am a beginner in BEHAT. I just took a basic sample script and tried to execute the same in firefox / chrome driver, but facing issues in executing.

My Behat.yml:

## behat.yml

default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
browser_name: chrome
default_session: selenium2
javascript_session: selenium2
selenium2:
wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"

The script executes successfully , but its not opening the browser and executing.

Started the selenium driver by: java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Automation\geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar

Comment: show us your whole yml file please

Comment: Below is my yml file,
# behat.yml
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
browser_name: firefox
default_session: selenium2
javascript_session: selenium2
selenium2:
wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the *Selenium* passing the absolute path of the *WebDriver* variants either through double back slashes `(\\)` or through single forward slash `(/)` as follows :

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar
```

Comment: HI Debanjan, Hav e tried java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\\Behat\\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar , buit the same error exists. Test passed but the browser is not opened